# What event will be triggered by 'fireAllRules' of drools?

Tags: drools

I'm using Drools 7.73.0.Final and I want to make a time consuming monitor which needs the time when `fireAllRules()` is triggered(as a base time).

I hope there is a event invoked when using `fireAllRules()`, so that I can use `EventListener` instead of adding duplicate timing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd look into a Listener for this use-case, since it would be difficult to define proper semantic of global entry/exit in case of fireUntilHalt.

I believe you can easily wrap your call of `fireAllRules()` and decorate it with entry/exit calls.

Alternatively, you can consider implementing your own specialization of the FireAllRules Command, again to capture entry/exit, and invoke Session API with the Command.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! In addition, do you know what tools can record the time consumption of the LHS and RHS parts of the Drools rule? This is the main reason why I want to make the time consuming monitor.

Comment: For the RHS, you might refer to BeforeActivationFiredEvent and AfterActivationFiredEvent, which are on a per-rule basis from the `AgendaEventListener` interface.

Comment: For the LHS I'm not sure you can really measure _what you expect_, as when rules are compiled into a rete/Phreak network, they are interweaved there.

Comment: This is all spot-on. My previous company (admittedly with a slightly older version of Drools) did exactly this, and we had a AgendaEventListener based implementation which would measure execution time for individual rules. The Listener framework is amazingly extensible and useful, but it's important to understand the rule lifecycle and phases (especially how matching works, with 'update' and 'insert' calls) ... that understanding will also help explain why LHS measuring doesn't make sense at all. ;)